# VS2010 penwin.h missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, include

I have a very old MFC program which has been updated through from VS6.0 to VS2005.

Now we are looking to migrate to VS2010, and it is having trouble finding *<penwin.h>*.

It is available in the VC8\include directory for VS2005, but no counterpart in the VC10.0\include directory.

Does any one know what I can do in such a situation? 
I cant find any documentation on this was well, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

penwin.h is related to [Window Pen Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_for_Pen_Computing) which is an obsolete API long ago.

See Step 6 here (MSDN):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986837.aspx

You should remove this include file and try to build your project (correct other errors and remove other stuff related to this API since it is no longer supported).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I will have to deal with the errors.

Comment: There is no other way, sorry.